# Android UI Automator wait orientation change applied

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

I am making tests using Android UI automator FW. I am trying to detect memory leak during device orientation change using following code:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation()
                            .setRotation(orientation);
```

It changes device orientation, but my questions is:

What is a proper way (except sleep) to wait that device finished orientation change?

I've tried:

```
mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(<MyPackage>).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
```

Sometimes work, sometimes not.

```
mDevice.waitForIdle();
```

Not working at all.

Any other ways to wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [UiDevice.setOrientationXXX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#setOrientationLeft()) methods instead of [UiAutomation.setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html#setRotation(int)).

The UiDevice methods have a build in call to [UiDevice.waitForIdle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#waitForIdle()) which will block until the UI has not changed for at least 500ms.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like:

```
mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(<MyPackage>).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
```

fails to wait if executed too early, so i made it like so:

```
SystemClock.sleep(500); // minimal activity restart time is about 300ms
mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(<MyPackage>).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
```

It makes actual waiting if restart takes more then expected, but still not 100% proper waiting.

Who knows better answer?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use below code? I think it seems to be worked.

```
mDevice.waitForWindowUpdate(null, 5000);
```

Comment: i've tried it, but seems it's always waits 5000 ms. My solution works faster, but don't skip orientations.

Comment: Just keep in mind that if the packet name is not the same, it will return immedialtely (as stated in the API). So instead of "null" you should use the packet name of your activity. It might still wait for a window update. So unless you have other update sources, this might work (at least it does for me).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, it set the device orientation to the left and then go back.

```
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
device.setOrientationLeft()
device.setOrientationNatural()
```